# Java 7 Cannot retrieve information from an object

Tags: java

This is my first post so sorry if it's not done right. This program is for my AP Computer Science course (I do not want a sample of code, just an explanation of why this is happening). Whenever I try to get a variable from an object, I get an error that says the variable does not exist(NetBeans IDE). Thanks in advance!

This is the code:

```
public class AnnualFuelTester 
{   
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        AnnualFuelUse Fill1 = new AnnualFuelUse(1, 1,  45023, 45231, 10.00, 2.95);
        AnnualFuelUse Fill2 = new AnnualFuelUse(2, 4,  45231, 45480, 11.70, 2.99);
        AnnualFuelUse Fill3 = new AnnualFuelUse(3, 8,  45480, 45659,  9.30, 3.03);
        AnnualFuelUse [] FillArray = {Fill1, Fill2, Fill3};

        System.out.println("Fillup    Days    Start Miles    Distance    Gallons        Consumed    MpG    Fuel Price    Cost");
        **int temp = Fill1.distance;**
        System.out.printf ("%4.1f     %4.1f   %4.1f          %4.1f       %4.1f                   %4.1f  %4.1f         %4.1f", );
    }
}
```

(edit:) AnnualFuelUse:

```
public class AnnualFuelUse 
{
    private int dist = 0;
    private double MpG = 0;
    private double CoT = 0;
    private double totals = 0;
    private double projection = 0;
    private double min = 0;
    private double max = 0;

    Annual_Fuel_Use(int fillTemp, int daysTemp, int startTemp, int stopTemp, double gallTemp, double priceTemp){
        int fillNumber = fillTemp;                                       
        int daysSinceLastFill = daysTemp;                                       
        int startMiles = starttemp;                                     
        int stopMiles = stoptemp;                                       
        int distance = Annual_FuelUse.travelDistance(startMiles, stopMiles);
        double fuelConsumed = galltemp;
        double mPG = AnnualFuelUse.milesPerGal(dist, fuelConsumed);
        double pricePerGallon = pricetemp;
        double tripCost = AnnualFuelUse.costOfTrip(pricePerGallon, fuelConsumed);
    }

    public double getMilesPerGal(){
        return MpG;        
    }

    public int getTravelDistance(){
        return dist;        
    }

    public double getCostOfTrip(){
        return CoT;        
    }

    public double getTotals(){
        return totals;
    }

    public double getProjection(){
        return projection;
    }



    public int travelDistance(int distance1, int distance2){   
        dist = distance2 - distance1;
        return dist;
    }

    public double milesPerGal(int travelDistance, double fuelConsumed){        
        MpG = travelDistance / fuelConsumed;
        return MpG;
    }

    public double costOfTrip(double pricePerGal, double fuelConsumed){        
    CoT = pricePerGal * fuelConsumed;
        return CoT;
    }

    public double totals(double dat1, double dat2, double dat3){
        totals = dat1 + dat2 + dat3;
        return totals;
    }

    public double projection(int days,double projected){
        projection = (projected / days) * 365;
        return projection;
    }

    public double dataMin(int dat1, int dat2, int dat3){
        if (dat1 <= dat2){
            min = dat1;
        }
        if (min <= dat3){
            return min;
        } else {
            return dat3;
        }
    }

    public double dataMax(int dat1, int dat2, int dat3){
        if (dat1 >= dat2){
            max = dat1;
        }
        if (max >= dat3){
            return max;
        } else {
            return dat3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what does `Annual_Fuel_Use` look like?

Comment: IMO this syntax is so far from Java convention..

Comment: Please try to be more specific what your problem is. On which line do you get the error? If it is in the `int temp = Fill_1.distance;` you need to add the definition for `Annual_Fuel_Use`.

Comment: `(I do not want a sample of code, just an explanation of why this is happening)` - The variable you try to reference on the line specified by your compiler does not exist. Can't be more specific without more information - what what `Annual_Fuel_Use` look like?

Comment: @Sorceror he said he's a beginner. You can't expect him to know all Java conventions yet.

Comment: @Philipp if he know how to write the class.. As soon as beginner discovers conventions then better..

Comment: could you explain what I did wrong please?

Comment: @user1879127: it's not that big problem, it's just better for you to adopt those convention fast, they will help you to manage code readability as well as reading code after another java programmers. You might start with this article [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm), more you'll code more you'll use other convention rules.. Short way the brackets are in java at same line as class/if/for/etc.., and java uses camelCase for classes and variable names (see the article for more info)..

Comment: ah, thanks alot. I've had trouble with reading my code.

Comment: You have removed the static, now try removing the variables in the constructor you are discarding,  not setting fields when all you are doing is returning a value, and write you min/max methods by only using Math.min/max.

Comment: If you are interested, here is my profile http://www.linkedin.com/in/peterlawrey

Comment: thanks, but no thanks. Not yet at any rate

Comment: could you give me an example of what I should remove? I don't completely understand what you mean

Answer (score 2):

I have just noticed you have incorrectly used `static` fields.  You should avoid setting static fields in a constructor as this leads to a nightmare of confusion.

I suggest you

- make all your fields non-static, and any methods which use them non-static. If you don't do this all your objects are actually using the same fields, not their own.
- make you getters match your field names.  Try to keep as much consistency as possible or this can lead to confusion as well.  For example if you have a `travelDistance` make the fields the same name as well.  If you want to make it clear make the getter method `getTravelDistance`
- don't set lots of variables you then discard.  Only keep code which is useful and this can be confusing as well.
- don't use underscores in class names.

In general you need to work of your consistency, e.g. your min/max method are half implemented using Math and half your own code.

I suggest you fix all your code before you continue.

Comment: How do I use the same getter three times like that though?

Comment: call otherwise three times. I assume you want to use it into printf.  in that case call it three times with s `,` in between.

Comment: i'm sorry, but I what is otherwise?

Comment: "otherwise" is what my auto-correct thought it should be. :|  I meant you can call each of the getters exactly the same way.

Comment: ah, thanks. I still get the "cannot reference non-static variable in a static context"

Comment: Thanks, i've fixed it. Should I update the code in the question as well?

Comment: :P this is my first semester of AP Computer Science (online). So I have to tinker with things until it works or I give up and turn to the web for help.

Comment: Happy to help, let me know when you have updated the code in your question.

Comment: “Perfection is achieved perfection not when there is nothing left to add, but when there is nothing left to take away” – Antoine de Saint-Exupery

Comment: And remove all the `_` as these are not conventional.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I don't see and `distance` variable but I do see `dist` and that too is private.

Create getters for your fields as

```
 public int getDist(){
   return dist;
 }
```

Then use then in your `Annual_Fuel_Tester` class as

```
int temp = FILL_1.getDist();
```

Comment: ah, I thought I fixed that dist variable. The problem with the getter method is that all the objects are already initialized, so the getter method only returns the fill_3 data

Comment: @user1879127 don't make the variables static

Comment: when I do that, I get a "non-static variable cannot be referenced in a static context"

Answer (score 1):

You have some basic flaws in the design of your Java (bean) class, and as you can see, this is leading to issues in using it.

- The most immediate problem is one of scope/visibility. Your class variables are declared private, which means they are not visible outside of the class itself. In order to use them the way you are now (in the main method), you would need to make them public or package-private. But dont! See point below.
- You are correct to make your class variables private, this is due to the principles of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). An object should hide as much of its internal implementation as possible, while providing a consistent interface to interact with it. What you are missing is getters/setters that can be used by callers to manipulate the internal state of your object. Add them in!
- Your class variables are just that - class variables! This is because you have made them static. This means all instances of your class will share the same values - I'm pretty sure thats not what you intended. Fix this by removing the static keyword on those fields. Also remove the static keyword from all the classes methods.
- Lastly, you are not using good [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Doing so makes your code more readable, both to yourself, and others. Trust me, you will be able to identify, diagnose, and fix bugs much faster if you follow these conventions than if you dont.

Your Java (bean) class should look something like this:

```
public class AnnualFuelUse {
    private int dist = 0;
    private double MpG = 0;
    private double CoT = 0;
    private double totals = 0;
    private double projection = 0;

    // Constructors

    // Non-static getters/setters

    // Other methods
}
```

And your calling class should look something like this:

```
public class AnnualFuelTester {   
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        AnnualFuelUse fill1 = new AnnualFuelUse(1, 1,  45023, 45231, 10.00, 2.95);
        int temp = fill1.getDistance();
    }
}
```

That should get your started in the right direction.

Comment: the constructor cannot reference the non-static method, why is that?

Comment: Whats your question, @user1879127?